# what are the tax implications of surrendering a USA green card

Tags: usa, taxes, greencard, non-residents, non-citizens

I have been a legal permanent resident of the USA for over 30 years and now plan to live in Europe and surrender my green card.  What are the tax implications of becoming a non-resident alien on social security and other US income?

Comment: Assuming you haven't checked whether you can receive benefits or not: https://www.ssa.gov/international/payments_outsideUS.html. There's also a non-resident alien tax tool: https://www.ssa.gov/international/AlienTax.html